# Jackson insisting in throwing confusing exception when deserializing a POJO

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson

I cannot find why I get an exception from Jacksoin even if everything looks ok.

I have the following ***Json***:

```
      {
        "id": "8a599509-994a-4cff-ad6d-c3f770e8d159",
        "action": "0",
        "code": "13",
        "device_id": "0BC813D9-37FE-4FAB-9FA0-05F85CBAE777",
        "branch_id": "0BC813D9-37FE-4FAB-9FA0-05F85CBAE999",
        "description": "Sergio sei uno stra-figo",
        "date": "2021-11-09T10:22:45",
        "severity": 1
      }
```

And the class I need to deserialize the Json to:

```
@JsonIgnorePropenter code hereerties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class LogMdto {

private String id;

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

@JsonProperty(value = "object_id")
private String objectId;

@Size(max = Log.objectNameSize, message = "size may not by bigger than " + Log.objectNameSize)
@JsonProperty(value = "object_name")
private String objectName;

@JsonProperty("device_id")
private String deviceId;

@NotNull(message = "may not be null")
private String description;

@NotNull(message = "may not be null")
@Size(max = Log.codeSize, 
        message = "size may not by bigger than " + Log.codeSize)
private String code;

private Integer action;

private String id;

private int severity;

@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")
private Timestamp date;


public Timestamp getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(String date) {
    DateTimeFormatter dft = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME;
    this.date = Timestamp.valueOf(LocalDateTime.from(dft.parse(date)));
}

public String getObjectId() {
    return objectId;
}

public void setObjectId(String objectId) {
    this.objectId = objectId;
}

public String getObjectName() {
    return objectName;
}

public void setObjectName(String objectName) {
    this.objectName = objectName;
}

public String getDeviceId() {
    return deviceId;
}

public void setDeviceId(String deviceId) {
    this.deviceId = deviceId;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public String getCode() {
    return code;
}

public void setCode(String code) {
    this.code = code;
}

public Integer getAction() {
    return action;
}

public void setAction(Integer action) {
    this.action = action;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public int getSeverity() {
    return severity;
}

public void setSeverity(int severity) {
    this.severity = severity;
}
```

}

When I call `ObjectMapper().readValue(json, LogMdto.class)` I get the following excepion;

> Unrecognized field "device_id" (Class com.plintech.LorikeetNestSpring.models.dto.mobile.LogMdto), not marked as ignorable

I do not understand why this exception. The field *deviceId* is mapped with @JsonProperty("device_id"), I have setter and getter but I still an error.

***UPDATE***

I have done the following changes:

```
//Removed the annotation
private String deviceId;
```

....
....

Changed setter and getter as follows:

```
@JsonProperty(value = "device_id")
public String getDeviceId() {
    return deviceId;
}

@JsonProperty(value = "device_id")
public void setDeviceId(String deviceId) {
    this.deviceId = deviceId;
}
```

But the result is always the same exception, I don't understand what is wrong with my code and I cannot figure out what else I can try to make sure there aren't other hidden issues.

Answer (score 2):

If I am not mistaken, since it is a private field, then the Field `@JsonProperty` annotation itself is not used, but rather the Getter/Setter.

The Getter/Setter will be used for serialization/de-serialization and in both cases they do not match `device_id` name;

To Fix it: Add `@JsonProperty` to your Getter/Setter.

On the other hand, if it was a public variable, then the below without Getter/Setter would work fine:

```
@JsonProperty("device_id")
public String deviceId;
```

=== Tested Code ===

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class LogMdto {

    private String id;

    @JsonProperty(value = "object_id")
    private String objectId;

    @JsonProperty(value = "object_name")
    private String objectName;

    private String deviceId;

    @NotNull(message = "may not be null")
    private String description;

    @NotNull(message = "may not be null")
    private String code;

    private Integer action;

    private int severity;

    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")
    private Timestamp date;


    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public Timestamp getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        DateTimeFormatter dft = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME;
        this.date = Timestamp.valueOf(LocalDateTime.from(dft.parse(date)));
    }

    public String getObjectId() {
        return objectId;
    }

    public void setObjectId(String objectId) {
        this.objectId = objectId;
    }

    public String getObjectName() {
        return objectName;
    }

    public void setObjectName(String objectName) {
        this.objectName = objectName;
    }
    @JsonProperty("device_id")
    public String getDeviceId() {
        return deviceId;
    }
    @JsonProperty("device_id")
    public void setDeviceId(String deviceId) {
        this.deviceId = deviceId;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public Integer getAction() {
        return action;
    }

    public void setAction(Integer action) {
        this.action = action;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getSeverity() {
        return severity;
    }

    public void setSeverity(int severity) {
        this.severity = severity;
    }
}
```

---

> ```
> public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
>     String jsonTest = "{\n" +
>             "        \"id\": \"8a599509-994a-4cff-ad6d-c3f770e8d159\",\n" +
>             "        \"action\": \"0\",\n" +
>             "        \"code\": \"13\",\n" +
>             "        \"device_id\": \"0BC813D9-37FE-4FAB-9FA0-05F85CBAE777\",\n" +
>             "        \"branch_id\": \"0BC813D9-37FE-4FAB-9FA0-05F85CBAE999\",\n" +
>             "        \"description\": \"Sergio sei uno stra-figo\",\n" +
>             "        \"date\": \"2021-11-09T10:22:45\",\n" +
>             "        \"severity\": 1\n" +
>             "      }";
>
>     LogMdto logMdto = new ObjectMapper().readValue(jsonTest, LogMdto.class);
>
>     System.out.println(logMdto.getDeviceId());
> }
> ```

---

Log:

```
0BC813D9-37FE-4FAB-9FA0-05F85CBAE777
```

Comment: Added @JsonProperty("device_id") @JsonGetter("device_id")  and @JsonSetter("device_id") ... to the getter and setter respectively ... same error

Comment: Please see updated code @Sergiob    It is your exact code.  If something is not working, could be related to your jackson dependencies then.  Make sure you have the latest version if possible.  (Please see that properties are Private).  I dont like public fields :)

Comment: If I declare public the property works, but that is not what I need. It must stay private and with the getter setter doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

The answer from Susan is correct.

You have to add the `@JsonProperty("device_id")` to your getters and setters.

To avoid Errors like these, you could always use a `AnySetter` that keeps the data that could not be correctly mapped.

For example:

```java
public class LogMdto {
....

    private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<>(); // This Map holds all the properties that were not found.
    // You could check what is wrong with the names that this POJO receives from your JSON

    @JsonAnyGetter
    public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
        return this.additionalProperties;
    }

    @JsonAnySetter
    public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
        this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
    }

....
```

Comment: I tried... no way.. same problem.. look at the update. It works only if I declare public device_id (same name as in the json). It looks like @JsonProperty is ignored because I must also change the name otherwise it doesn't work.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, thank you all for your help, but the answer is a little more subtle. There is nothing wrong with the code, the problem is that the mapper is not the right one, it was imported by mistake the

> org.codehaus.jackson

version instead of

> fasterxml

.... changed the import directive... everything was fine again.